# zsh Command Auto correction

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, autocorrection

I've seen and read about zsh offering auto correction of a command input. Eg- if I type sl, it should ask me something like "did you mean ls?" But, in my zsh, this does not happen. It just gives an error.
Is there a reason for this, some settings maybe?
(And yes, I'm sure that I'm running zsh and not bash or something)

Answer (score 5):

This is controlled by the `CORRECT` option, see `zshoptions(1)`.

```
% zsh -f
dhcp196-230% setopt correct
dhcp196-230% sl
zsh: correct 'sl' to 'ls' [nyae]? y
...
dhcp196-230% setopt nocorrect
dhcp196-230% sl
zsh: command not found: sl
dhcp196-230%
```